# GoogleApp Directory API's to set the Proxy credentials

Tags: google-api, google-apps, google-api-java-client, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

I am using GoogleApps Directory api to access the Googleapps. I have one query regarding Proxy , how to set the proxy credentials using directory API's.

As per googleApps API's documentation i can use class "GoogleNetHttpTransport" to set the Proxy (port and host).

static HttpTransport newProxyTransport() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
    NetHttpTransport.Builder builder = new NetHttpTransport.Builder();
    builder.trustCertificates(GoogleUtils.getCertificateTrustStore());
    builder.setProxy(new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 3128)));
    return builder.build();
  }

But if i have credentials for proxy server then how can i set, there is no mention about setting up proxy credentials.

Is there any GoogleApps api which allow to set proxy credentials along with hostname and port?

If no , then should i go for setDefault(Authenticator) which will set the proxy credentials to system property ?

Can anyone have idea about this. Any input on this is highly appreciable!

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/proxy_setup). For HTTP proxy with the Java client library, if your corporate proxy server were running on `my.proxy.domain.com`, on port `3128`, you could add the following to your code before creating a service object for Google Calendar, Google Spreadsheets, etc.

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "my.proxy.domain.com");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "3128");
```

Alternatively, this can be done on the command line when starting your servlet environment:

```
java -Dhttp.proxyHost=my.proxy.domain.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=3128
```

You may also refer with this related thread: [Google Directory API using Service Account via Proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32767661/google-directory-api-using-service-account-via-proxy)